# Dynamically disable a dropdown of reactive form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying disable a dropdown built with ul and li i have to use ui and li instead of select for requirement inside a reactive form.

Html

```
<ul data-dropdown data-value class="bx--dropdown" tabindex="0">
     <li class="bx--dropdown-text">Validation type</li>
     <li>
       <ul class="bx--dropdown-list">
        <li data-option [attr.data-value]="input" class="bx--dropdown-item"   *ngFor="let input of validationTypes;">
         <a class="bx--dropdown-link" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">{{input}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

ts

```
let fieldSetGroup = <FormArray>this.createTemplateForm.get("fieldSets");
        fieldSetGroup.push(this.fb.group({
            key: ["", Validators.required],
            "type": ["", Validators.required],
            mandatory : ["", Validators.required],
            validationType: [""]
}));
let fg  = <FormGroup> fieldSetGroup.controls[id];
if (fg.controls["key"] === "Apple") {
  fg.controls["validationType"].disable();
}
```

tried adding formControlName on both ul and li...didnt work...How to handle this case?

Comment: you want to dsable <li> or<a>..? and what is the condition for disableing..?

Comment: @Edison Disable of <ul>/complete dropdown and condition of disabling is if one of the fields of reactive form is not empty and has got some value.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options either use reactive form or use css class

for useing reactive form  add `formControlname` to your component

```
<ul data-dropdown data-value class="bx--dropdown" tabindex="0" formControlName="validationType">
     <li class="bx--dropdown-text">Validation type</li>
     <li>
       <ul class="bx--dropdown-list">
        <li data-option [attr.data-value]="input" class="bx--dropdown-item"   *ngFor="let input of validationTypes;">
         <a class="bx--dropdown-link" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">{{input}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and add below code in your method (where you WANT TO disable it)

```
const ctrl = this.fg.get('validationType');
  ctrl.disable();
```

To achice this using css
  add this in your component css

```
.disabled{
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity:0.4;
  }
```

and in ur html add this calss to your element

```
 <ul data-dropdown data-value class="bx--dropdown" tabindex="0" [class.disabled]="fg.invalid">
     <li class="bx--dropdown-text">Validation type</li>
     <li>
       <ul class="bx--dropdown-list">
        <li data-option [attr.data-value]="input" class="bx--dropdown-item"   *ngFor="let input of validationTypes;">
         <a class="bx--dropdown-link" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">{{input}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Please replace `fg.invalid` with your validetion condition

Comment: Thanks,But both the methods didn't work for me,ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with path: 'fieldSets -> 0 -> validationType' for first approach.

Comment: please replace YOUR VALIDETION CONDITION with this `"fg.invalid` 
 in `[class.disabled]="fg.invalid"`

Comment: inside my validation condition is it? if (mycondition) { fg.invalid}?

Comment: Modified in a question

Comment: change `[class.disabled]="fg.invalid"` to `[class.disabled]=fieldSetGroup.values.key =='apple'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215504/discussion-between-new123-and-edison).